# Graphics Drivers do not show up on System Info or Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

So I've been having problems with a few games since I first switched over to Ubuntu about 3 weeks ago (very much still a noob, yes). I fixed a couple bugs with certain games, but on the whole I think it might be that my graphics drivers need an update.

My system is running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Dell Studio 1550 with a Intel Core i5 CPU M 430@2.27GHz × 4 n and 4 GB RAM, graphics card is just a standard Intel Integrated Graphics card, though I am currently unsure of which one.

Tried to manually find the drivers on Intel's website, but became a bit confused and overwhelmed with the number of links and information thrown at me.

My question is, really, can anyone help me to figure out how to download and install the updated drivers?

Comment: as much as i know, the intel drivers is already in the kernel so don't have to download and install. what problems do you have?       I can suggest you to install meas-util and DRIconf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more simple to write here (:

so install [mesa-utils [image: Install mesa-utils]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mesa-utils)

and also install DRIconf:
install from the software center:
[image]

and after that, change the "enable S3TC texture..." to YES as shown here:
[image]

Comment: Identified my card as soon as I did all of this, thanks a lot :)

Comment: glad i helped (:

Comment: and may it be protected or somthing like? it may help other, no? (: